# Express: defining REST API with sub-resources?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I implemented a REST API via Express.
I got a list of suppliers, and for each one list of inventory.
the URL went:
/Supplier/Inventory{supplierId} (e.g http://MyServer/Supplier/Inventory/237 to get inventory list of supplier 237)

So... pretty standard stuff: in my server.js I use: (and I simply here but you guys get the idea)

```
const routeInventory = require('./routes/Inventory');
...
app.use('/api/Supplier/Inventory', routeInventory);
```

and in routes file:

```
outer.route('//:id').get(ShowInventory);
```

and the function would be something like:

```
exports. ShowInventory=  (req, res, next) => { 
    const iSupplierId=req.params.id;
    console.log('ShowInventory for SupplierId:' + iSupplierId);
...
}
```

very simple. req.params.id gives me the param I need from the URL.
So far so good. But! somebody here insists that since Inventory is a sub-entity of supplier, the URL should be:

/Supplier/{supplierId}/Inventory

so two questions:

1. Are they correct? is that the standard?
2. no matter how much I play with the express code, I can't get the {supplierId} parameter when its in the middle of the URL... how is that done?

Thanks Much

Comment: `/supplier/{supplierId}/inventory` is correct. Also kebab-case is recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you request subresources of a certain resource then you should indicate an id of a resource and only after that indicate subresource name:

```
/supplier/{supplierId}/inventory
```

As of routing this can be achived like this:

```
router.get('/supplier/:supplierId/inventory', ShowInventory)
```

that way you can access `supplierId` like this:

```
const supplierId = req.params.supplierId
```

Comment: Thanks. it works, i can map the route, but a call to it (e.g. .../supplier/237/inventory) does not give me the parameter in req.params.supplierId (req.params is empty, as a matter of fact). any idea? seems like req.params will have the value only at the end of the URL...?

Comment: Sorry! i got it. doing it in the router:
router.route('/:supplierId/ProductLineXrefsForSupplier').get
did the trick. before, I tried in the main server.js file:
app.use('/XRefs/:supplierId/blabla', xref); - as the 'base' URL, and that indeed didn't work